# Type 'List<Map<String, String?>>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast

Tags: flutter, dart

**Context**: I want to register new customer to my API server(with package:http/http.dart).

**Problem**: This error was thrown:

```
flutter: type 'List<Map<String, String?>>' is not a subtype of type 'String' in type cast
```

I think flutter is complaining about the type of `metadata` property, but I have no clue on how to resolve it.

I tried to create a `Map<dynamic, dynamic>` object but it does not help as well.

```dart
var response = await _httpClient.post(
        createCustomerUrl,
        body: {
          'email': customerModel.email,
          'first_name': customerModel.firstName,
          'last_name': customerModel.lastName,
          'password': customerModel.password,
          'username': customerModel.username,
          'meta_data': [
            {'key': 'birthdate', 'value': customerModel.birthdate},
          ],
        },
      );
```

Answer (score 3):

@Abbasihsn answer was almost there. `JSON.encode` + `'Content-Type': 'application/json'`  in the headers solve the problem.

```dart
var response = await _httpClient.post(
        createCustomerUrl,
        body: json.encode({
          'email': customerModel.email,
          'first_name': customerModel.firstName,
          'last_name': customerModel.lastName,
          'password': customerModel.password,
          'username': customerModel.username,
          'meta_data': [
            {'key': 'birthdate', 'value': customerModel.birthdate},
          ],
        }),
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' }
      );
```

The error message is due to `http` package internally perform type check and trying to cast the body to Map<String, String>. Here is the code snippet extracted from the `http` package that causes the error:

```dart
  /// Sends a non-streaming [Request] and returns a non-streaming [Response].
  Future<Response> _sendUnstreamed(
      String method, Uri url, Map<String, String>? headers,
      [body, Encoding? encoding]) async {
    var request = Request(method, url);

    if (headers != null) request.headers.addAll(headers);
    if (encoding != null) request.encoding = encoding;
    if (body != null) {
      if (body is String) {
        request.body = body;
      } else if (body is List) {
        request.bodyBytes = body.cast<int>();
      } else if (body is Map) {
        request.bodyFields = body.cast<String, String>();  // <-- this line
      } else {
        throw ArgumentError('Invalid request body "$body".');
      }
    }

    return Response.fromStream(await send(request));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

try encoding your body to a `JSON`, like this:

```
var response = await _httpClient.post(
        createCustomerUrl,
        body: json.encode({
          'email': customerModel.email,
          'first_name': customerModel.firstName,
          'last_name': customerModel.lastName,
          'password': customerModel.password,
          'username': customerModel.username,
          'meta_data': [
            {'key': 'birthdate', 'value': customerModel.birthdate},
          ],
        }),
      );
```

Comment: Sadly not working, `json.encode` return a stringified version of the request body, but the server is expecting the request body to be key-value pair json, when passing the string to server, server complain missing params.

Comment: ok, have you tried `json.encode` only for `meta_data': [...],` section?

Comment: I have solved, you are almost there, the solution is `json.encode` with explicitly add `Content-Type: application/json` to the headers. Thank you for helping.

Comment: your welcome. if my answer was helpful, I would be grateful if you vote it up or set it as an acceptable solution.